# Form inputs in same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I'm trying to make a simple form that has inputs and each input is in col-md-6, i want each two input to be next to each other, then at the bottom i have a input of type file and the uploaded file (i want it an image here), should appear in a square beside the last two inputs on the left side, here is an image of what im trying to achieve: [image: What i want], and here is my code:

```js
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#ImgUpload').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <form>
                  <h4>Personal Details</h4>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                  <label>Input</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                  <label>Input</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                  <label>Input</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                  <img id="ImgUpload" src="#"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                  <label>Image</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                  <label>Input</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
               </div>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve using 2 row elements < div class="row" >

The first surrounds the first 4 inputs and the second surrounds the remaining 3.